# Do I need minikube if I'm using a k8 cluster in Azure Cloud?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, minikube

I'm trying to deploy a simple API into an AKS and want to show it off to the internet using an ingress controller. I want to know if I'm using cloud do I need to install minikube?

Answer (score 2):

Minikube is designed for local Kubernetes development and testing. It supports one node by default. So it is not related to your AKS setup, i.e you don't need minikute for AKS.

To be able to demo your setup on the Internet, you can set up an AKS but be mindful of securities and make sure that you are not exposing your entire cluster on the Internet.

Comment: By default, minikube will spin up 1 single node, but you can have more than one node.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out and found the link here for multiple nodes setup. https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/multi_node/